# ListBox SelectedItem Background color scheme?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

When we select ListBox item we get a Bluish background color right? How can i access that style and apply it to a different control? 
i.e how can i use that selected item background color as a style elsewhere?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ListBoxItem uses colors from the SystemColors class, which are pulled from Windows. Specifically, this trigger is what changes the background:

```
<Trigger Property="IsSelected"
 Value="true">
<Setter TargetName="Bd"
    Property="Background"
    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
<Setter Property="Foreground"
    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
</Trigger>
```

So you can either use it like above (i.e. Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}", or you could access the colors directly (i.e. "{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrush}").

Same goes for code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a direct property so I believe what you will have to do is to change the whole template.

If you speak french, look at this link. I believe it contains everything you need to know :

http://www.developpez.net/forums/d899479/dotnet/developpement-windows/windows-presentation-foundation/wpf-listviewitem-definition-style/